# which jquery plug-in for bootstrap data grid

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

Any jquery plug-in that can give me an editable data-grid with drop-downs and popups on specific columns? Where I can also have some fixed rows etc.

I have a bootstrap table which i just want to look better and let the user do in-line editing (like excel), sorting, paging, and binding drop-downs, custom popups etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Js-Grid

here is official example [Js-Grid](http://js-grid.com/demos/)